# Can't install SQL Server command-line tools on Ubuntu due to `unmet dependencies`

Tags: sql, sql-server, ubuntu, multiarch

After sucessfully installing *Sql Server* Following [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu), Failed to install *SQL Server command-line tools* on Ubuntu 20.04. Efforts led to below commands and results:

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

> OK

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list
```

> deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/prod bionic main

```
sudo apt-get update
```

> Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
>   Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]
>   Hit:3 http://x.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
>   Hit:4 http://x.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
>   Hit:5 http://x.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
>   Hit:6 ... packages . microsoft . com/ubuntu/18.04/mssql-server-2019 bionic InRelease
>   Hit:7 ... packages . microsoft . com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal InRelease
>   Hit:8 ... download . gocd . org  InRelease
>   Hit:9 ... packages . microsoft . com/ubuntu/18.04/prod bionic InRelease
>   Get:10 ... security . ubuntu . com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [21.3 kB]
>   Get:11 ... security . ubuntu . com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [31.5 kB]
>   Fetched 160 kB in 17s (9,288 B/s)
>   Reading package lists... Done

```
sudo apt-get install mssql-tools unixodbc-dev
```

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   mssql-tools is already the newest version (17.5.2.1-1).
>   Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>   The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    mssql-tools : Depends: msodbcsql17 (>= 17.3.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
>    unixodbc-dev : Depends: unixodbc (= 2.3.7)
>                   Depends: odbcinst1debian2 (= 2.3.7) but it is not going to be installed
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I tried following the dependency failure tree to install unmet dependencies manually but in the final step failed to install:

```
sudo apt-get install multiarch-support
```

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Package multiarch-support is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
>   is only available from another source
>
> E: Package 'multiarch-support' has no installation candidate

How would you solve these issues to finally install the Command line?

Comment: If you're using Ubuntu 20.04, why are you trying to install the 18.04 packages?

Comment: yep! seems the docs are outdated :))

Comment: 20.04 isn't officially supported yet, so not outdated, simply relevant to what's supported.

Comment: Ok, btw thank you.

Comment: Still not "supported". Idk why MS wants to waste our time. If I want to install postgresql it's 1 command and I'm done.

Answer (score 12):

Using:

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list
```

Instead of:

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list
```

Solves the issue, The docs are out dated or maybe Ubuntu 20.04 is not officially supported yet...

Also I wasn't able to use `curl https://...` (Don't know why always peer closed my connection!) so I manually downloaded the link and paste the result to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list`